# How to add a text graphic to a sequence using ExtendScript in Adobe Premier Pro?

Tags: premiere, extendscript

Inside Adobe Premiere, you can use the "Type Tool" to insert a text graphic onto a sequence. Is it possible to do the same action from an ExtendScript (.jsx)?

Comment: The answer is yes, the problem is that for some reason Adobe have never released any documentation for extendscript in Premiere. Go figure.